# Why does systemd report job failure for some services with Type=simple?

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl

According to [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=), systemd will report success as soon as the child process have forked off. This is consistent with results from my quick test:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/test.service
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/asdfg
$ systemctl daemon-reload
$ systemctl start test  # Exits immediately
$ echo $?
0
$ systemctl status test
● test.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-12-15 01:56:52 CST; 2s ago
  Process: 24483 ExecStart=/bin/asdfg (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 24483 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 15 01:56:52 iBug-Server systemd[1]: Started test.service.
Dec 15 01:56:52 iBug-Server systemd[24483]: test.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Dec 15 01:56:52 iBug-Server systemd[24483]: test.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/asdfg: No such file or directory
Dec 15 01:56:52 iBug-Server systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 15 01:56:52 iBug-Server systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
$
```

However, according to my past experiences, systemd reports failure like this when a start or a restart of some services fails, for example `nginx` or `ssh`:

```
Job for test.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status test.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Why isn't systemd reporting failure for my test service (matches its man page on Freedesktop.org) but for other services?

Clarify: I mean specifically the command `systemctl start/restart`. By "report failure", it prints out messages and exits with a non-zero status. Output of `systemctl status` is irrelevant.

Comment: You're going to confuse answerers asking why no failure is being reported when the output that you present has the word "failed" in it.  Four times.

Comment: Are nginx or sshd services of `Type=simple`?

Comment: @muru I had always assume so, but how stupid I was! Neither of them is of `Type=simple` (nginx is `forking` while ssh is `notify`, at least for Debian Buster and Ubuntu Disco).